# OctoberCMS - builder plugin: Prevent the partial from being called if the current record has not yet been created

Tags: plugins, backend, builder, partial, octobercms

I use the builder plugin and a partial in it. If I enter data in the partial without saving the actual record first, I get an sql error (SQLState [23000]: **Integrity violation constraint: 1048 column 'item_id' cannot be null...**).

How can I let the partial check if the corresponding record is already there? (or how can I prevent the partial from being called if the current record has not yet been created, i.e. saved?).

Supplementary information:
The attached pictures illustrate the basic problem.

First I integrate the partial control into my model.
[image: Used element from the control list of the Builder Plugin]
[image]

Then I create the required relationships etc. on the code level.
Finally I can access the partial in my new plugin.

[image: Access to the embedded partial.]

And this is where the problem arises. I must first create the record under **General** (i.e. enter data there and click on Save.). Otherwise I get the above error message.

I'm looking for an option, which checks whether the click on **Create Translations** first checks whether the corresponding record already exists.

Comment: can you add more details so we can understand if better

Comment: @Hardik Satasiya: please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: thanks for that i will check it and let you know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.

The reason for the Integrity violation constraint was that the foreign key to the item ID (item table) must be **nullable in the translation table**.

However, this results in the problem that an item can be created with a translation but without the corresponding item data.